# Поиск минимального и максимального значения в массиве отрицательных и положительных чисел с разделением

Tags: c++, массивы

У меня возникла проблема с поиском минимального и максимального числа в массиве. Я хочу сделать, создание и автозаполнение массива. При этом нужно разделить вывод минимального и максимального значения для положительных и отрицательных чисел.

Например:
Для положительных чисел:
Максимум = 63
Минимум = 21

Для отрицательных чисел:
Максимум = -34
Минимум = -2

Я написал такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a[10],i,min,max;
  int min1,max1;
  srand(time(0));
  for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
    a[i]=-50+rand()%100;
    cout<<a[i]<<"\t";
    }
  max=a[0];
  min=a[0];
  max1=a[0];
  min1=a[0];

  for (i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
     if(a[i]>0 && max<a[i]) max=a[i];
     if(a[i]>0 && min>a[i]) min=a[i];
     if(a[i]<0 && max1<a[i]) max1=a[i];
     if(a[i]<0 && min1>a[i]) min1=a[i];
    }
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"For positive numbers: "<<endl;
  cout<<"Max is "<<max<<endl;
  cout<<"Min is "<<min<<endl;

  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"For negative numbers: "<<endl;
  cout<<"Max is "<<max1<<endl;
  cout<<"Min is "<<min1<<endl;
}
```

Проблема в том, что программа **игнорирует**, то что нужно находить минимальное и максимальное число в одном случае только для положительных, а в другом только для отрицательных, и в следующем массиве: 
**1, -14, -2, -22, -16, 30, -8, -34, 14, 17**;
Для положительных чисел максимальным будет число 43, а минимальным -6.
Для отрицательных чисел максимальным будет число -1, а минимальным -47.

При этом бывает и такое, что в отрицательных *min* и *max* тоже появляются положительные числа, вместо отрицательных.

В чём проблема?

Comment: жаль что не C# - так сильно хотел написать свою реализацию LINQ с одной фичей

Comment: ты перепутал их местами: `Максимум = -34 Минимум = -2`! или ты по модулю искал?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в этом:

```
max=a[0];
min=a[0];
max1=a[0];
min1=a[0];
```

---

```
max = -1;
min = -1;
max1 = 1;
min1 = 1;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  if (a[i] > 0)
  {
    if (max == -1)
    {
      max = a[i];
      min = a[i];
    }
    if (max < a[i]) max = a[i];
    if (min > a[i]) min = a[i];
  }
  // similar for min1 and max1
}
```

Comment: что не так? это какая-то фича C++?

Comment: @dgzargo Не фича, а ошибка в логике - если a[0] - положительное, то использование его  для отрицательных максимумов неверно и т.п.

Comment: я не обратил на это внимания. тогда... присвоить `null` и начинать с нулевого индекса!?

Answer (score 0):

```
max = 0;
min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
max1 = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
min1 = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (a[i] > 0) {
        if(max < a[i]) max = a[i];
        if ( min > a[i]) min = a[i];
    }
    else {
        if ( max1 < a[i]) max1 = a[i];
        if ( min1 > a[i]) min1 = a[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int GetMaxPositiveNumberInArray(int * pArray, size_t arraySize)
{
    int maxValue = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        if (pArray[i] > 0 && pArray[i] > maxValue)
            maxValue = pArray[i];

    return maxValue;
}

int GetMaxNegativeNumberInArray(int * pArray, size_t arraySize)
{
    int maxValue = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        if (pArray[i] < 0 && pArray[i] < maxValue)
            maxValue = pArray[i];

    return maxValue;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
{
    int intArray[200];
    const size_t arraySize = sizeof(intArray) / sizeof(int);

    // заполнение массива рандомными числами
    for (int& value : intArray)
        value = rand() - 16000; // отнимаем 16000 что-бы дать шанс появиться отрицательным числам

    cout << "Max positive number: " << GetMaxPositiveNumberInArray(intArray, arraySize) << endl;
    cout << "Max negitive number: " << GetMaxNegativeNumberInArray(intArray, arraySize) << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```